# Angular variables

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I've got a line of text right now, and when that line of text is being overflown something gets set to true which let's me load in a tooltip! Code below:

**Template**

```html
<div>
   <p #tooltip [tooltip]="/* ShowToolTipSomeHow? ? name : null */" delay="300">{{name}}</p>
</div>
```

This is where it should check if it should show the tooltip or not. As you can see it should somehow detect if the tooltip should be shown or not, I have no idea how and that's my question right now.

**Component**

```js
@ViewChildren('tooltip') private tooltips!: QueryList<ElementRef>;

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.tooltips.changes.subscribe((tts: QueryList<ElementRef>) => {
      tts.forEach((tooltip, index) => {
        this.checkTooltipTruncated(tooltip);
      });
    });
  }

  private checkTooltipTruncated(tooltip: ElementRef) {
    // Checks if the text has overflown
    const truncated = this.isTextTruncated(tooltip);

    if (truncated) {
      // Change the ShowToolTipSomehow? value?
    }
  }
```

In the component it somehow changes some value that the tooltip can detect so that it can update itself to hide the tooltip. The additional problem is that it's not 1 tooltip to change, but infinite tooltips (so basically 1 or more).

My question is, how would I do this because I'm pretty stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Create an array that holds boolean values and using the tooltip elements index set the value in the array.

ts:

```
@ViewChildren('tooltip') private tooltips!: QueryList<ElementRef>;
tooltipsVisible: boolean[];

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    if (!this.tooltipsVisible) {
       this.tooltipsVisible = new Array(this.tooltips.length).fill(false);
    }
    this.tooltips.changes.subscribe((tts: QueryList<ElementRef>) => {
      tts.forEach((tooltip, index) => {
        this.checkTooltipTruncated(tooltip, index);
      });
    });
  }

  private checkTooltipTruncated(tooltip: ElementRef, index) {
    // Checks if the text has overflown
    const truncated = this.isTextTruncated(tooltip);

    if (truncated) {
      this.tooltipsVisible[index] = true;
      // Change the ShowToolTipSomehow? value?
    }
  }
```

html:

```
<div>
   <p #tooltip [tooltip]="tooltipsVisible[i] ? ...." delay="300">{{name}}</p>
</div>
```

You should create your p elements using *ngFor you can have the index available in your template...